# Updating values in summary tables after script loads all products

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html-table, datatables

I am working on building a script that summarises info for products and I would like to place the summary table to the top of the page.

The problem is that the values per products are being added up while processing the product information. Thus the totals table shows 0 for everything, as the totals table is being loaded before the product information is being processed.

Situation changes if I place the summary table in the code to the bottom - then it works correctly.

**Is there any way how to make the totals work (totals table ID = itemtabtotals) with the summary table at the top?**

The values in the code that i am talking about are the following: 
$NUM_products, $SUM_sold_QTY, $SUM_prices, $AVG_price, $SUM_bena_prices, $AVG_bena_price, $SUM_costs, $AVG_costs, $SUM_profits, $AVG_profit, $soldQuantity

```
                if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
                        $SUM_sold_QTY = 0;
                        $NUM_products = 0;
                        $AVG_price = 0;
                        $AVG_bena_price = 0;
                        $AVG_costs = 0;
                        $AVG_profit = 0;

                        ?>
                        <table style="border: 1px solid black;" class="widefat" id="itemtabtotals">
                            <thead>
                                <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Celkem<br>Prodáno (Ks)<br></th>
                                <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Vzorek produktů<br>(Ks)</th>
                                <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Průměr<br>Prodejka (CZK)</th>
                                <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color: #009944;">Průměr<br>BENAclub (CZK)</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Průměr<br>Náklady (CZK)</th>
                                <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Průměr<br>Zisk (CZK)</th>
                                <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Průměr<br>Zisk (%)</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tr style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700; text-align: center;">
                                <td class="num"><?php echo $SUM_sold_QTY; ?></td>
                                <td class="num"><?php echo $NUM_products; ?></td>
                                <td class="num"><?php echo $AVG_price; ?></td>
                                <td class="num" style="color: #009944;"><?php echo $AVG_bena_price; ?></td>
                                <td class="num"></td>
                                <td class="num"><?php echo $AVG_costs; ?></td>
                                <td class="num"><?php echo $AVG_profit; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo round($AVG_profit / $AVG_costs * 100);?>%</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table><br>
                        <table class="widefat" id="itemtab">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="min-width: 100px; font-weight: 600;">Prodáno (Ks)<br><input style='font-size: 12px; max-width: 60px; min-height: 20px; margin-left: -3px; margin-top: 3px;' id='solditems' onkeyup='searchTablesolditems()' type='text' placeholder='Filtrovat..'></th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600;">Produkt<br><input style='font-size: 12px; max-width: 60px; min-height: 20px; margin-left: -3px; margin-top: 3px;' id='items' onkeyup='searchTableitems()' type='text' placeholder='Filtrovat..'></th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Prodejka (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color: #009944;">BENAclub (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color: #c62201;">Akce/Sleva (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Náklady (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Zisk (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color: #000;">Zisk (%)</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <?php $i = 0; 

                            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
                                $wp_query->the_post();

                                $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

                                if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
                                    $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());

                                    $product_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                                    $product_bena_price = (ceil(($product_price - ($product_price*(0.06)))/10) *10-1);
                                    $product_sale_price = $product->sale_price;

                                    $costs = (ceil((get_post_meta($product, 'custom_cost_field', true ))/100) *85); // Suppose 15% margin on products

                                    if ($costs == '') {
                                        $costs = ceil($product_price*0.7);
                                    }

                                    $profit = intval($product_price) - $costs;
                                    $profitsale = intval($product_sale_price) - $costs;
                                    $profitperc = round(($profit / $costs)*100);
                                    $profitpercsale = round(($profitsale / $costs)*100);
                                }

                                elseif ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
                                    $product = new WC_Product_Variable(get_the_ID());

                                        foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $variation) {
                                            $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
                                            $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);

                                            $var_regular_price = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true); // $variation->get_regular_price();
                                            $var_bena_price = (ceil(($var_regular_price-($var_regular_price*(0.06)))/10) *10-1);
                                            $var_sale_price = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_sale_price', true); // $variation->sale_price;

                                            $var_costs = ceil($var_regular_price*0.7);
                                            $var_profit = intval($var_regular_price) - $var_costs;
                                            $var_profitsale = intval($var_sale_price) - $var_costs;

                                            $var_profitperc = round(($var_profit / $var_costs)*100);
                                            $var_profitpercsale = round(($var_profitsale / $var_costs)*100);
                                        }
                                }

                                // $stockQuantity = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_stock', true);
                                $NUM_products = $show_posts;

                                $SUM_sold_QTY += $soldQuantity;
                                $SUM_prices += $product_price += $var_regular_price;
                                $AVG_price = round($SUM_prices / $NUM_products);

                                $SUM_bena_prices += $product_bena_price += $var_bena_price;
                                $AVG_bena_price = round($SUM_bena_prices / $NUM_products);

                                $SUM_costs += $costs += $var_costs;
                                $AVG_costs = round($SUM_costs / $NUM_products);

                                $SUM_profits += $profit += $var_profit;
                                $AVG_profit = round($SUM_profits / $NUM_products);
                                $soldQuantity = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'total_sales', true);
                                $product_price_ok = true;

                                if ($costs > $product_price) {
                                    $product_price_ok = false;
                                } ?>
                                <tr <?php echo($i % 2 == 0 ? 'class="alternate" style="background-color: #f0ffe0;"' : ''); ?>>
                                    <td class="num"><div><?php echo $soldQuantity; ?></div></td>      
                                    <td><a href="<?php echo get_edit_post_link(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                                    <td class="num" <?php echo(!$product_price_ok ? 'style="background-color: #FFA4A4;"' : 'style="background-color: #B2FFB2;"'); ?>><div><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { echo $product_price; } elseif ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) { echo $var_regular_price; }?></strong></div></td>
                                    <td style="color: #009944;" class="num"><div><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $product_sale_price; } else { echo $product_bena_price; }} elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $var_sale_price; } else { echo $var_bena_price; }} ?></strong></div></td>
                                    <td style="color: #c62201;" class="num"><div><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $product_sale_price; }} elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $var_sale_price; }}?></strong></div></td>
                                    <td <?php echo(!$product_price_ok ? 'style="background-color: #FFA4A4;"' : ''); ?> class="num"><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { echo $costs; } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { echo $var_costs; }?></td>
                                    <td class="num"><font color="green"><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $profitsale; } else { echo $profit; }} elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { if ($var_sale_price > 0) { echo $var_profitsale; } else { echo $var_profit; }}?></strong></font></td>
                                    <td class="num" style="font-size: 14px; <?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { echo($profit < 20 ? 'background-color: yellow;' : ''); echo($profit > 59 ? 'background-color: transparent;' : ''); echo($profit > 19 && $profit < 60 ? 'background-color: lightgreen;' : ''); } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { echo($var_profit < 20 ? 'background-color: yellow;' : ''); echo($var_profit > 59 ? 'background-color: transparent;' : ''); echo($var_profit > 19 && $var_profit < 60 ? 'background-color: lightgreen;' : ''); } ?>"><font color="#000"><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $profitpercsale; } else { echo $profitperc; }} elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { if ($var_sale_price > 0) { echo $var_profitpercsale; } else { echo $var_profitperc; }} ?>%</strong></font></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php $i++;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </table>
                        <?php
                    }
                    wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: There's no javascript code in your question and it's not even obvious whether you use jQuery DataTables (which you tagged your question with). If you seek DataTables solution, share relevant code and, I'm pretty sure, I can give simple jQuery solution.

Comment: Well, I was wondering if the table could be for example refreshed using javascript - I already tried some options but unsuccessfully. I´d be happy if you could share some of your solutions. Thank you :o)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods that you could use:

**Method 1**: use 2 queries. The first is an aggregate query which would return all the SUM, AVG etc values. The second query would just get the raw data - like you do now but no need for the calculations.

**Method 2**: instead of outputting the data immediately - store it in a string. The string can be thought of as a template which would allow you to change parts of the string. For example: instead of `<td class="num"><?php echo $SUM_sold_QTY; ?></td>` you could use `$str = '<td class="num">[SUMSOLDQTY]</td>';` Later on in your code you could use `$x = str_replace("[SUMSOLDQTY]", $SUM_sold_Qty, $str);`

When processing is finished just echo the variable.

Comment: I pasted my reply into another answer- unfortunately, it did not work :(.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I used Method 2, which suits my code the best at this moment, but eventually the values wonˇt replace for some reason.

Did I place the x at the wrong place? :S I tried several locations... but no result.

See entire code below. I am also adding a screen of the result. The top table does not even have the rows - only the head :S.

[image: Image result]

```
                    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
                        $SUM_sold_QTY = 0;
                        $NUM_products = 0;
                        $AVG_price = 0;
                        $AVG_bena_price = 0;
                        $AVG_costs = 0;
                        $AVG_profit = 0;
                        ?>

                        <table style="border: 1px solid black;" class="widefat" id="itemtabtotals">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Celkem<br>Prodáno (Ks)<br></th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Vzorek produktů<br>(Ks)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Průměr<br>Prodejka (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color: #009944;">Průměr<br>BENAclub (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Průměr<br>Náklady (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Průměr<br>Zisk (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Průměr<br>Zisk (%)</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700; text-align: center;">
                                    <?php

                                    $str1 = '<td class="num">[SUMSOLDQTY]</td>';
                                    $str2 = '<td class="num">[NUMPRODUCTS]</td>';
                                    $str3 = '<td class="num">[AVGPRICE]</td>';
                                    $str4 = '<td class="num">[AVGBENAPRICE]</td>';
                                    $str5 = '<td class="num">[AVGCOSTS]</td>';
                                    $str6 = '<td class="num">[AVGPROFIT]</td>';
                                    $str7 = '<td class="num">[AVGPROFITPERC]</td>';

                                    ?>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table><br>
                        <table class="widefat" id="itemtab">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="min-width: 100px; font-weight: 600;">Prodáno (Ks)<br><input style='font-size: 12px; max-width: 60px; min-height: 20px; margin-left: -3px; margin-top: 3px;' id='solditems' onkeyup='searchTablesolditems()' type='text' placeholder='Filtrovat..'></th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600;">Produkt<br><input style='font-size: 12px; max-width: 60px; min-height: 20px; margin-left: -3px; margin-top: 3px;' id='items' onkeyup='searchTableitems()' type='text' placeholder='Filtrovat..'></th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Prodejka (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color: #009944;">BENAclub (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color: #c62201;">Akce/Sleva (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Náklady (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">Zisk (CZK)</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color: #000;">Zisk (%)</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <?php $i = 0; 

                            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
                                $wp_query->the_post();

                                $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

                                if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
                                    $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());

                                    $product_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                                    $product_bena_price = (ceil(($product_price - ($product_price*(0.06)))/10) *10-1);
                                    $product_sale_price = $product->sale_price;

                                    $costs = (ceil((get_post_meta($product, 'custom_cost_field', true ))/100) *85); // Suppose 15% margin on products

                                    if ($costs == '') {
                                        $costs = ceil($product_price*0.7);
                                    }

                                    $profit = intval($product_price) - $costs;
                                    $profitsale = intval($product_sale_price) - $costs;
                                    $profitperc = round(($profit / $costs)*100);
                                    $profitpercsale = round(($profitsale / $costs)*100);
                                }

                                elseif ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
                                    $product = new WC_Product_Variable(get_the_ID());

                                        foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $variation) {
                                            $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
                                            $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);

                                            $var_regular_price = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true); // $variation->get_regular_price();
                                            $var_bena_price = (ceil(($var_regular_price-($var_regular_price*(0.06)))/10) *10-1);
                                            $var_sale_price = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_sale_price', true); // $variation->sale_price;

                                            $var_costs = ceil($var_regular_price*0.7);
                                            $var_profit = intval($var_regular_price) - $var_costs;
                                            $var_profitsale = intval($var_sale_price) - $var_costs;

                                            $var_profitperc = round(($var_profit / $var_costs)*100);
                                            $var_profitpercsale = round(($var_profitsale / $var_costs)*100);
                                        }
                                }

                                // $stockQuantity = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_stock', true);
                                $NUM_products = $show_posts;

                                $SUM_sold_QTY += $soldQuantity;
                                $SUM_prices += $product_price += $var_regular_price;
                                $AVG_price = round($SUM_prices / $NUM_products);

                                $SUM_bena_prices += $product_bena_price += $var_bena_price;
                                $AVG_bena_price = round($SUM_bena_prices / $NUM_products);

                                $SUM_costs += $costs += $var_costs;
                                $AVG_costs = round($SUM_costs / $NUM_products);

                                $SUM_profits += $profit += $var_profit;
                                $AVG_profit = round($SUM_profits / $NUM_products);
                                $AVG_profitperc = round($AVG_profit / $AVG_costs * 100);
                                $soldQuantity = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'total_sales', true);
                                $product_price_ok = true;

                                if ($costs > $product_price) {
                                    $product_price_ok = false;
                                } ?>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr <?php echo($i % 2 == 0 ? 'class="alternate" style="background-color: #f0ffe0;"' : ''); ?>>
                                        <td class="num"><div><?php echo $soldQuantity; ?></div></td>      
                                        <td><a href="<?php echo get_edit_post_link(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                                        <td class="num" <?php echo(!$product_price_ok ? 'style="background-color: #FFA4A4;"' : 'style="background-color: #B2FFB2;"'); ?>><div><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { echo $product_price; } elseif ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) { echo $var_regular_price; }?></strong></div></td>
                                        <td style="color: #009944;" class="num"><div><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $product_sale_price; } else { echo $product_bena_price; }} elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $var_sale_price; } else { echo $var_bena_price; }} ?></strong></div></td>
                                        <td style="color: #c62201;" class="num"><div><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $product_sale_price; }} elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $var_sale_price; }}?></strong></div></td>
                                        <td <?php echo(!$product_price_ok ? 'style="background-color: #FFA4A4;"' : ''); ?> class="num"><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { echo $costs; } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { echo $var_costs; }?></td>
                                        <td class="num"><font color="green"><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $profitsale; } else { echo $profit; }} elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { if ($var_sale_price > 0) { echo $var_profitsale; } else { echo $var_profit; }}?></strong></font></td>
                                        <td class="num" style="font-size: 14px; <?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { echo($profit < 20 ? 'background-color: yellow;' : ''); echo($profit > 59 ? 'background-color: transparent;' : ''); echo($profit > 19 && $profit < 60 ? 'background-color: lightgreen;' : ''); } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { echo($var_profit < 20 ? 'background-color: yellow;' : ''); echo($var_profit > 59 ? 'background-color: transparent;' : ''); echo($var_profit > 19 && $var_profit < 60 ? 'background-color: lightgreen;' : ''); } ?>"><font color="#000"><strong><?php if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) { if ($product_sale_price > 0) { echo $profitpercsale; } else { echo $profitperc; }} elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { if ($var_sale_price > 0) { echo $var_profitpercsale; } else { echo $var_profitperc; }} ?>%</strong></font></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            <?php $i++;
                                $x1 = str_replace("[SUMSOLDQTY]", $SUM_sold_Qty, $str1);
                                $x2 = str_replace("[NUMPRODUCTS]", $NUM_products, $str2);
                                $x3 = str_replace("[AVGPRICE]", $AVG_price, $str3);
                                $x4 = str_replace("[AVGBENAPRICE]", $AVG_bena_price, $str4);
                                $x5 = str_replace("[AVGCOSTS]", $AVG_costs, $str5);
                                $x6 = str_replace("[AVGPROFIT]", $AVG_profit, $str6);
                                $x7 = str_replace("[AVGPROFITPERC]", $AVG_profitperc, $str7);
                            }
                            ?>
                        </table>
                        <?php
                    }
                    wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Your problem is solved easily using DataTables [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option that triggers custom code (filling your summary table) upon DataTable readiness. But, unfortunately, you didn't share your jQuery code, so I can't post exact code that resolves your issue.

Comment: And two more things - you shouldn't post response to the answer as another answer and it is a bad choice to cook up table's HTML server-side, DataTables can do that perfectly on its own.

Comment: This is currently all I have, I do not have any jQuery :(.

Comment: I have answered similar questions on several occasions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082810/how-to-add-a-column-sum-feature-to-my-datatable/57091409#57091409) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760560/how-do-i-calculate-the-average-of-the-tr-column-in-the-table/55761502#55761502), for instance), but it requires you to modify jQuery code. Otherwise, there's not much I can do for you.